# Detect lines in fencing match

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I have input an youtube video of fencing 
Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEIlrENogN0

I want to get output with the same video, but I want to get highlighted areas with white lines.

Screenshots from video:

[Input image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hGQU.jpg)

[Input image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEZY5.jpg)


Result I want:

[Output I want #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9ePh.jpg)
[Output I want #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvtjg.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by fencing lines? Please provide frame of the video and desired result on separate images

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, the question is unclear

Comment: Thank you for responses! I ve edited question so hope now its more understandable